# validation on discount between 0 and 0.999 in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I need to apply validation on discount filed accept value between 0 and 0.999

like: 0.25, 0.0125, 0.09

I tried

```
'discount'             => 'required|max:0.999'
```

but got: The discount may not be greater than 0.999 characters.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been downvoted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'discount'             => 'required|numeric|max:0.999'

Answer (score 2):

The `max` rule looks at the type of the variable being sent to it and applies the appropriate logic. For numbers, it works like you intend - it compares the numerical value.

But for strings, it means that the string may not be longer than the max. In your case, Laravel thinks you're sending a string and tries to validate it as such. Your variables probably aren't `0.25`, `0.5`, etc., but rather `"0.25"`, `"0.5"`, etc. If you convert them to floats, it should work fine.

If, for instance, your values come directly from forms, they're most likely in string form, not float.

Answer (score 0):

Size is what you need here

> The field under validation must have a size matching the given value.
>   For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For
>   numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. For files,
>   size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes.

```
'discount'             => 'required|size:0.999'
```

Comment: the same error: The discount must be 0.999 characters.

Comment: This doesn't work because `size` requires an exact match. You want `required|numeric|max:0.999` or `required|numeric|between:0,0.999`